# How can I export a database from ddev?

Tags: ddev

ddev currently lacks an export-db command (see https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/767)

How can I export a database?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the `ddev export-db` command. You can do many things (from `ddev export-db -h`):

```bash
ddev export-db --file=/tmp/db.sql.gz
ddev export-db -f /tmp/db.sql.gz
ddev export-db --gzip=false --file /tmp/db.sql
ddev export-db > /tmp/db.sql.gz
ddev export-db --gzip=false > /tmp/db.sql
ddev export-db myproject --gzip=false --file=/tmp/myproject.sql
ddev export-db someproject --gzip=false --file=/tmp/someproject.sql
```

In addition, don't forget about `ddev snapshot`, which is a great and quick way to make a quick dump of your db, but it's not as portable as a text-based dump. (See `ddev snapshot -h` and `ddev restore-snapshot -h`.)

**Using traditional techniques inside the container**:

Because DDEV has all the familiar tools inside the container you can also use commands like mysqldump and mysql and psql inside the container:

```
ddev ssh
mkdir /var/www/html/.tarballs
mysqldump db | gzip >/var/www/html/.tarballs/db.sql.gz
# or with explicit authentication
mysqldump -udb -pdb -hdb db | gzip >/var/www/html/.tarballs/db.sql.gz
```

or for Drupal/drush users:

```
ddev ssh
drush sql-dump --gzip >.tarballs/my-project-db.sql.gz
```

That places the dump in the project's .tarballs directory for later use (it's on the host).

See [database management docs](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/basics/database_management/) for more info.

Comment: I come back to this answer every now and then when I have to create a dump.

Comment: Just doing `ddev export-db -h` will give you a much quicker answer :) It has loads of examples.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's very usefull to have the TYPO3 pendant for this, thanks to Outdoorsman for the comment on GitHub Issue above.

> Outdoorsman wrote:
>
> I'm coming from the TYPO3 CMS world and also agree this would be a
> good thing to have. I currently use

`ddev ssh and ./vendor/bin/typo3cms database:export | gzip > project_name_db.sql.gz`

> if the typo3_console
> extension is installed via composer.

Answer (score 1):

Also You could use [Drupal console](https://drupalconsole.com/):

```
ddev start
ddev ssh    
drupal database:dump
drupal database:restore --file db-2018-07-04-11-31-22.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

To explain more on @rfay answer, i generally prefer `drush cli`, however, its based on preference .

```
ddev start
ddev ssh
drush sql:dump --result-file=../db-export.sql
```