# I need to update ddev on all my projects, how can I do that?

Tags: ddev

My ddev installation has gotten quite old... I've just been going along quite happily with v1.0, and now they're at v1.5.0. How do I catch up? Is it hard? What are the risks?

Answer (score 2):

There are two major things that I can think of in recent releases:

1. We switched from bind-mounted databases to docker-volume mounted databases.
2. We upgraded to Mariadb 10.2, TYPO3 v8 has trouble with MariaDB 10.2, but not much else does.

Here's what I recommend:

- Get a db dump of each project. I save dumps like that in a directory named .tarballs in the project.  (Use the original techniques from [How can I export a database from ddev?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50123540/how-can-i-export-a-database-from-ddev/50123541#50123541) or do it however you like. If your version already has `ddev export-db` use that). Having reasonable db dumps around is always a good idea.
- Make a good backup of ~/.ddev where the databases were stored until about v1.2 (they now live on docker volumes).
- Make a good backup of your projects.
- Make sure all your projects have been rm'ed (ddev list should show nothing, preferably `docker ps -a` should show nothing). If you have a version with the feature, just use `ddev rm -a`
- Move your ~/.ddev out of the way. `mv ~/.ddev ~/.ddev.bak` so you don't even *have* those bind-mounted databases any more.
- Upgrade ddev to the [latest version](https://github.com/drud/ddev/releases)
- In each project as you come to it, `ddev config` it and then `ddev start` and `ddev import-db` from your saved db dump.

Comment: Works fine so far. Upgraded an installation from 1.0 to 1.5. First few projects run great after importing the db dump.